# How to get the mean of the last 1, 2, 3, ... elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector like

```
vec<-c(1,5,3,6,10)
```

How do I quickly get the median of the last 1, 2, 3,... elements in the list?  In other words, I want to return the median for each of the following subvectors

```
c(10)
c(6,10)
c(3,6,10) ...
```

So my final result should be a vector equivalent to c(10,8,6,4.5,3).  I know I can use median(tail(vec,n)) to get the median of the last n elements, but how do I apply this for n over the set 1:length(vec) without using a slow for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example using `tail` , you can loop over your vector and extract the nth last elements:

```
sapply(seq_along(vec),
       function(x)median(tail(vec,x)))
[1] 10.0  8.0  6.0  5.5  5.0
```